Can't launch drive for desktop (macos Sequoia 15.2) (Google Drive Version: 100.0.2.0 (Apple Silicon) (File Provider))
I have been using Google Drive for desktop on my M1 MacBook Pro for a long time, but recently my folders on my google drive stopped syncing suddenly (Some folders are on my windows laptop and drive just basically mirrors them to my mac). On my other devices drive is running completely fine. There is no problem of storage shortage on my account too.
At first, I signed out and signed in but that did not work. So I completely uninstalled and reinstalled it, but in vain. I was seeking help from google high tier support team but nothing really worked for my Mac.
I have attached what pops out after the sign in. I have searched on the internet for a long time but to my surprise I did not found a single person with my kind of problem. The troubleshooting I tried are mentioned below:

Signing out and in
Uninstall and reinstall
Using mac on a different network
Signing in with a different google account
Deleting the DriveFS folder and restarting the computer
Reset user preferences on drive
Google drive proxy setting change from Auto-Detect to Direct Connection

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!


What did the Google Support team recommend, and what was their conclusion after it didn't work?

They just told me to do those things I mentioned as a list, but nothing really worked and they did not go further with this issue.

If you create a new user account on your Mac, and try to connect to your Google drive from that account, does it work?

yes it worked! From my user account on mac, no google account can be used to launch google drive. But when I created a 2nd user account on my mac, in this account I am able to use drive for desktop. And after that suddenly when I went back to my primary user account, this time drive worked normally. Can you mention the underlying issues due to which the drive was unable to launch in the first place?
